# NSString to NSData in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have written a code like this :

```
NSString *Input  = @"1";
NSMutableData *InputData = [Input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I expected that the InputData be 48 , but it was 31 .
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: In ASCII '1' is 49, not 48, which is 0x31.

Comment: @tommyo, you should add it as answer.

Comment: `-dataUsingEncoding:` won't return a mutable data object. just because you typed the variable `NSMutableData *` won't make it mutable. either type the variable `NSData *`, or call `mutableCopy` on the retrieved NSData object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Added as response by request)

In ASCII '1' is 49, not 48, which is 0x31. Are you maybe confusing them?